# Obtain a directory tree from a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, treeview

I'm trying to display a tree file structure and I had found many functions to do it, all of them take a directory as an argument, scan it and apply some logic that doesn't help me so much because I'm trying to do it from a JSON object converted to an associative array.

Here you can see the basic JSON structure:

```
"categories": [
   {
       "project-id": "666",
       "parent-id": "", //This means it is a parent category
       "name": "Parent category name",
       "count": "0",
       "id": "3668",  //This id value will be used in the parent-id  key on the child element 
       "elements_count": "0",
       "type": "FileCategory"
   },
   {
       "project-id": "666",
       "parent-id": "3668"
       "name": "Children category name"
       "id": "4587" 
       etc..
   },
```

and here part of the PHP array

```
array(2) { ["categories"]=> array(58) { 
[0]=> array(7) {
["project-id"]=> string(3) "666" 
["parent-id"]=> string(7) "3548745" 
["name"]=> string(13) "category name" 
["count"]=> string(1) "0" 
["id"]=> string(4) "3668" 
["elements_count"]=> string(1) "0" 
["type"]=> string(12) "FileCategory" }
[1]=> array(7) {
["project-id"]=> string(6) "667"
etc...
}
```

At the moment I'm just trying to figure it out how can I put a sub-folder (category) where it belongs.

for example:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $categoriesLenght; $i++) {
 if (empty($json_output['categories'][$i]['parent-id'])){ //if it has no parent then it is a "root" folder
        echo "<li class=\"root-directory\">" .$json_output['categories'][$i]['parent-id'] . "</li>";
    } else { //it is a subdirectory, but of what other category? How should I put it on the right place?
        echo "<li class=\"sub-directory\">" .$json_output['categories'][$i]['parent-id'] . "</li>";
    }
```

My desired output (at the moment) will be something like this:

```
Parent => 
      Child =>
           Child =>
      Child =>  
Parent => 
      Child =>
Parent =>
```

How can I print (or put) a subdirectory (of any level) in the category that it belongs? I know that maybe I should use the parent-id key for that, but I can't figure it out how.

Comment: So the issue is which parent to put the sub-directory in instead of just outputting a different css class name? You're need to create the correct tree array structure before hand or do some wacky output buffering when outputting . Go with option 1.

Comment: Easily done you just create a parent array with its key and put in children with the same parent-id which matches its key, then at the end do array_values to reset the parent array to something normal. Add more of an example json and ill answer.

Comment: Hi @LawrenceCherone at the moment I don't care about the CSS class, I'm worried about the structure of the tree. About the json, do you need more? what for?. Can you please provide some code?

Comment: Your example json is not showing how a child links to parent, its only showing 1 entry. Provide enough so a solution can be written, and also the expected output and I may provide some code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just edited my question, I hope it helps